# Embed python interpreter in embedded c application

Tags: c, ssh, lua, embedded, firmware

I'm working on an embedded c firmware to run on a server, I connect to this firmware through SSH.
I want to run some scripts in this firmware, so I want to embed Python interpreter so that once I run the script file (Written in Python) it's to be passed to python interpreter and the results are redirected to SSH again.

I have searched the internet for a possible solution, but all what I found is talking about embedding in windows application and using the normal hyper terminal for that.

Can anybody help me!

Comment: I would have thought that working the other way around (including some C-code to be used by python-code would be the easier way to go).

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [this](http://wiki.python.org/moin/EmbeddedPython). I would also take a look at [Lua](http://www.lua.org/), which is expressly designed / implemented to be eminently embeddable.

Comment: I'm now using LUA, but didn't start yet with integration, any suggestions.

Comment: Good choice. They have good documentation. And the project is designed to be very portable and embeddable. Just follow instructions, and come back with any questions. Don't forget to accept an answer that helped you.